# How to manipulate any route & request type with cy.intercept in Cypres.io?

Tags: javascript, http, request, cypress, intercept

Previously to [`Cypress 6.0.0`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#6-0-0), I was using the [`cy.server()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server) to set a `request header` on any `request` like so:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setHeaderToken', () => {
  cy.server({
    onAnyRequest: (route, proxy) => {
      proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('<CUSTOM-HEADER-HERE>', '<header-value-here>')
    },
  })
});
```

Then calling it in the `beforeEach` hook like so:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.setHeaderToken();
});
```

Now, I'm using [`Cypress 6.5.0`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#6-5-0) & I'm trying to accomplish the same functionality with [`cy.intercept`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) method like so:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setHeaderToken', () => {
  cy.intercept('/*', (req) => {
    req.headers['<CUSTOM-HEADER-HERE>'] = '<header-value-here>'
  });
});
```

This is not working, despite [if no `HTTP` method is defined Cypress will match all requests by default](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#method-String).

Comment: The docs are for the latest version. Does it apply to v6.5.0?

Comment: Yes, it applies for the context of my use case @Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `*` or `**/*` instead of `/*`, the leading slash does not work with minimatch.